# framebuffer image viewer (FBI) with plt.show (matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot my animation graph from the command line without starting the X server. I have found FBI (framebuffer image viewer) can do this. However I am unsure of how this will work I have tried to add it to my code:

```
fbi plt.show()
```

However this does not work. The reason I do not want to startx is because I am using the Raspberry Pi and therefore do not want to waste resources. Is there anyway of looking at the animation plot from the command line without starting X?

Thanks!

Comment: Interactivity with matplotlib plots fundementally depends on having an X-server.  However, if you just want to view your animation as a series of images using `fbi` it shouldn't be a problem. You'd just need to write them out to a temporary directory and then pass the list of images to `fbi`.